# Jquery - Hover did not start (bottom/right issue)

Tags: jquery, hover

I have a problem with the hover function.

**HTML**
`<div id="test" style="border:1px solid #ff0000; position:absolute; right:0px; bottom:0px; height:20px; width:100px;" ></div>`

**JQUERY**

```
$('#test').hover( function ()
    {
        $('#outp').append('enter <br />');  
    }, function ()
    {
        $('#outp').append('leave <br />');   
    });
```

**Demo**
http://jsfiddle.net/ky5fW/8/

When you enter (or leave) the div `test` on the bottom's side, jquery did not recognize it. 
But why?

Hope someone can help me.
Thanks in advance!
Peter

**EDIT:**
Strange, it works with the live function, but why?
 http://jsfiddle.net/ky5fW/11/

```
 $('#test').live('hover', function (event)
   {
       if (event.type == 'mouseenter')
       {
          $('#outp').append('enter 2 <br />');
       }
       if (event.type == 'mouseleave')
       {
          $('#outp').append('leave 2 <br />');
       } });
```

Comment: Which browser are you using? Works fine in Firefox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your cursor leaves the element via the window's chrome (the bottom or right hand side), the mouse leave event won't be fired. This is normal.

#### Update

> Strange, it works with the live function, but why?

Probably because `live()` doesn't attach events directly, but captures events bubbling up the DOM, and inspects the `event.target` to see which element triggered the event originally.

Answer (score 0):

The only work around is to place the element just inside the extents of the window so that the mouse movements can be captured before it hits the element with the hover event.

```
#test {
    border: 1px solid #ff0000; 
    position: absolute; 
    right: 2px; 
    bottom: 2px; 
    height: 20px; 
    width: 100px;
}

...

<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: I believe if you move the mouse fast enough it still won't trigger. See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ky5fW/10/).

Comment: This is true. In which case maybe using the mousemove event, with a flag to set current state (ie out or over), would suit better?